# AS3 Error #1034: Type Coercion failed is not thrown after clearing project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I am trying to load some assets from swc for example: MyAsset whose base class is Sprite. Everything works fine, until some time. some time after when building project it throws this error:

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@37b95f1 to assets.MyAsset
```

but after I clear project it builds successfully. I've tried to `trace(new MyAsset())` and it was throwing same error, so I think it could not load MyAsset from swc and after clearing project, It loaded assets from the very beginning.
I am curious if this kind of thing could happen in release build where everything is built successfully, but user loads swf and this happens? and if it can, what can I do in this case?

Comment: You have there somewhere a `var mc:MovieClip=something` that eventually gets assigned a `Sprite` descendant. You should review your codebase to lower types of variables as close to Object as possible. For example, if you only work with color transform, position, scaling and rotation, the variable can as well be `DisplayObject`, if you need its children, then its type can be `DisplayObjectContainer`.

Comment: `trace(new MyAsset())` this line also throws error. instantiating like this: `var myAsset:MyAsset=new MyAsset()` and as I mentiond in the question after clearing project everything works fine

Comment: Then check if there are multiple classes in your hierarchy named `MyAsset`. It's possible that project linking switched fully qualified class names, one is `asset.MyAsset` the other can be `myapp.MyAsset` for example.

Comment: nope. there is only one class named as MyAsset